# My JavaScript Post and Get functions with python server are out of order

Tags: javascript, python, post, server, get

For my class I am making a simple web app that essentially is a picture that can be commented on. The problem is every time I type in a new comment, it doesn't get displayed, but rather the previous comment gets displayed. It appears that the GET gets called before the POST can finish updating the list on the server. However, maybe the problem is somewhere else, I don't know.

I've done some research and it seems like the problem is due to asynchronization, however everything I've tried from reading up on that doesn't work the way I implement it, including callback functions.

Here is my code:

Javascript

```
var messages = []

function getData() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/bananas').then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        messages = []
        for (i=0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
            messages.push(data[i]);
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    })
}



function update() {
    var box = document.getElementById("messages");
    box.innerHTML = "";
    getData();
    for (i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.className = "comment";
        var curM = document.createTextNode(messages[i]);
        newDiv.appendChild(curM);
        box.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
    document.getElementById("comment").value = "";

}

update();


var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.onclick = function () {
    postData();
    update();

}

var clickenter = document.getElementById("comment");
clickenter.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
    }
});

function postData() {
    var content = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    if (content.length > 0) {

        message = "message=" + encodeURIComponent(content)
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/bananas', {
            body: message,
            method: 'POST',
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img src="image.jpg">
        <h2> Comments </h2>
        <div id="messages">
        </div>


        <textarea id="comment" type="text"> </textarea>
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">




    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

My Python server:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
import json

comments = []


class MyRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/bananas":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
            self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            self.end_headers()
            print(comments)
            jsonstring = json.dumps(comments)
            self.wfile.write(bytes(jsonstring, "utf-8"))

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == "/bananas":
            length = self.headers["Content-length"]
            length = int(length)
            if length > 0:
                body = self.rfile.read(length).decode("utf-8")
                strMessage = parse_qs(body)['message'][0]
                comments.append(strMessage)
                self.send_response(201)
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                self.end_headers()


def main():
    try:
        listen = ("127.0.0.1", 8080)
        server = HTTPServer(listen, MyRequestHandler)

        print("Listening...")
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("^C entered, stopping web server...")
        server.socket.close()

main()
```

Thanks

Comment: This is happening because you are executing the GET and POST requests at the exact same time. Give me just a few minutes and I will rewrite your code for you in an answer that will make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be everything that you need. I don't have any of the rest of your code, so I couldn't see if it runs properly or not, but the logic should be there.

```js
var messages = []
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var clickenter = document.getElementById("comment");

submit.onclick = function () {
  var content = document.getElementById("comment").value;
  
  if (content.length > 0) {
    postData()
      .then(function() {
        return getData();
      })
      .then(function(msgs) {
        update();
      });
  }
  else {
    getData()
      .then(function(msgs) {
        update();
      });
  }
  
  update();
}

clickenter.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});

update();

function getData() {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8080/bananas')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      messages = []
      for (i=0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        messages.push(data[i]);
        console.log(data[i]);
      }
      return messages;
    });
}

function update() {
    var box = document.getElementById("messages");
    box.innerHTML = "";
    for (i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.className = "comment";
        var curM = document.createTextNode(messages[i]);
        newDiv.appendChild(curM);
        box.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
    document.getElementById("comment").value = "";

}

function postData() {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8080/bananas', {
    body: "message=" + encodeURIComponent(content),
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I run it, I get the error `"app.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"` And line 42 refers to the line `.then(function() {` after the `postData()` call

Comment: You will have to post some more details on the rest of your code. Which library are you using for the `fetch()` function?

Comment: And I don't think I'm using any library, just whatever comes with javascript, Sorry, this is my first time working with servers.

Comment: Just fixed it, in you're original code, you forgot to define content in the postData function

Comment: @byurocks23 => Gotcha. Glad you got it figured out. :)